# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted in socket programming

Tags: sockets

Here is my below code which is throwing and exception "Only one usage of each socket address" **"listernerSocket.Bind(localEndPoint)"** , because of the LocalEndPoint is null.

For the first time it is working as expected and for the next time LocalEndPoint is becoming null and its trying to bind the same Ip and port number.

Thanks & regards,
Kartik

```
while (true)
                {
                    if (listernerSocket.LocalEndPoint == null)
                    {
                        listernerSocket.Dispose();
                        listernerSocket.Close();
                        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(assigningIp, Constants.MystroServicePortNo);
                        listernerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        listernerSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
                        listernerSocket.Listen(100);
                    }
                    var acceptedSocket = listernerSocket.Accept();
                    var state = new StateObject { BufferSize = 6000, Socket = acceptedSocket };
                    acceptedSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, this.ReadCallback, state);
                    acceptedSockets.Add(acceptedSocket);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply.

Actually your identification was write, which was because of the other method which was calling repeatedly and there LocalEndPoint was null.

Now its resolved.

Thanks & regards,
Kartik K